# Argument -r to restart the program in ShellScript

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have this code and I need to pass r in this read SCORE, just like de q for quitting, but now to restart the program. I am trying to do that using the command between $() but is not working. The program runs quite well, but when I pass "r" the bash do not restart the program, instead, it runs a program in background and I need to press ctrl+c to stop it. Any guess?

```
#!/bin/bash
# Calculate the sum of a series of numbers.
SCORE="0"
SUM="0"
while true; do
 echo -n "Enter your score [0-10] ('q' to quit): "
 read SCORE;
 if (("$SCORE" < "0")) || (("$SCORE" > "10")); then
 echo "Try again: "
 elif [[ "$SCORE" == "q" ]]; then
 echo "Sum: $SUM."
 break
elif [[ $SCORE == "r" ]]; then
    echo "Sum: $SUM"
    sleep 1
    $(bash ./aula03e07.sh);
    break
 else
 SUM=$((SUM + SCORE))
 fi
done
echo "Exiting."
```

Comment: please update the question and expand on the comment *`is not working`* ... does the script hang? does it print any messages? does it generate an error message? something else?

Comment: Did it! when I pass "r" the bash do not restart the program, instead, it runs a program in background and I need to press ctrl+c to stop it.

Comment: a google search on `bash restart script` brings up a few useful hits like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/356964) => try replacing `$(bash ./aula03e07.sh);` with `exec ./aula03e07.sh` or `$(basename $0)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helped me

Comment: @markp-fuso : Why _basename_? Wouldn't `exec bash $0` be  sufficient?

Comment: Just do `SUM=0`. No `sleep`, no `break`, don't launch another script. The loop will keep going with the sum reset to zero.